# How to set array total elements in for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

SECTION[1]="900px"
PATH[1]="/path/to/folder"

SECTION[2]="1080px"
PATH[2]="/patj/to/folder2"

SECTION[3]="3000px"
PATH[3]="/patj/to/folder3"

for i in {1..3}
do
    echo "${SECTION[$i]}"
    echo "${PATH[$i]}"
done
```

How can I make the for loop iterate through the number of sections?

I tried:

```
for i in {1.."${#SECTION[@]}"}
```

But I get an operand expected error.

Comment: Works for me with bash 4.3.48 if I only use builtin commands.. This might help: http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm on macos, I think the bash default bash version is 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the C like for loop syntax

```
for ((i=1;i <= ${#SECTION[@]};i++))
do 
    echo "${SECTION[$i]}"
    echo "${PATH[$i]}" 
done
```

Or with `seq`

```
for i in $(seq ${#SECTION[@]})
do 
    echo "${SECTION[$i]}"
    echo "${PATH[$i]}" 
done
```

Comment: That seq example looks so much more elegant - thanks so much. Love this place :-)

Comment: seq one around ~20-30% faster based on my tests but it required the seq command to be available.